# DAPPER argument is of wrong type, but no exception thrown

Tags: c#, rdbms

I have a bit of code (using dapper) that is executing a query against my database (ASE 12).  The sql has a where clause like this  **where r.reg_id = @reg_id**

Now in the database the reg_id column is a type of numeric, length 6, Prec 18, Scale 0

In the code the @reg_id variable is a Int32 and I would expect an exception to occur when I call the *async method query* but it just never errors out...

**QUESTION**:  *Is there a setting/configuration I need to set in dapper to get datatype errors to kick out exceptions?*

Code below will work because I set the datatype to decimal, but for other team members I would like for an exception to get kicked out so they know what the issue is... Any ideas?

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<CentersForRegIdResponse>> Handle(CentersForRegIdQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    sql.Append(" SELECT c.ctr_id, RTRIM(LTRIM(c.ctr_shname)) AS ctr_shname, RTRIM(LTRIM(r.reg_name)) AS reg_name ");
    sql.Append(" FROM center c, ");
    sql.Append(" region r ");
    sql.Append(" WHERE c.jcc_active = 'Y' and c.reg_id = r.reg_id and r.reg_id = @reg_id ");
    sql.Append(" ORDER BY  c.ctr_shname ");

    string query = sql.ToString();

    // custom mapping
    _dapperTools.DapperCustomMapping<CentersForRegIdResponse>();

    try
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = _dapperTools._aseconnection)
        {
            // example get list of rows by args
            var arguments = new
            {
                @reg_id = request.RegId
            };
            IEnumerable<CentersForRegIdResponse> allRows =
                    await dbConnection.QueryAsync<CentersForRegIdResponse>(query, arguments);
            return allRows;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _dapperTools.ReportSqlError(_log, query, ex);
        return null;
    }
}

public class CentersForRegIdQuery : IRequest<IEnumerable<CentersForRegIdResponse>>
{
    public Decimal RegId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If the underlying database doesn't error, why should Dapper? How is it to know that the database won't just coerce the value if possible, and **that's what the user wanted**? Sql Server will happily run this code: `declare @testValue int = 1;
select * from testTable where decimalValue > @testValue` against a decimal column.

Comment: That would be nice, but ASE 12 may not coerce it - at least from what I can tell.  The call to the database just never returns a value or anything and if I use swagger to manually execute the code it just spins and spins..never finishing.   Anyway, I would think there is a setting or configuration for this... I am using a ADO provider perhaps there is a setting for in it - a strict mode or such. { AdoNetCore.AseClient(0.13.1 via nuget)